# how to illustrate adding feature will increase the variance of first component in PCA geometrically

Tags: pca

How to geometrically illustrate

> Adding feature will increase the variance of first component in PCA

namely,  $\lambda_{max}\Big((X,u)^T(X,u)\Big) \geq \lambda_{max}\Big(X^TX\Big).$

Intuitively, the variance of new feature will be allocated into each component (by correlation), then the variance of old first component will increase, which must be smaller then the new first component.

But is there any clearly geometric explanation? I know the similar result of linear regression can be geometrically explained that the residual of projection on a line must be larger than on a plane (adding feature).

Comment: Upon characterizing this variance as the maximum of $v^\prime X v$ as $v$ varies over the unit sphere, *the conclusion follows immediately*, because the unit sphere in one higher dimension is a superset of the original unit sphere of vectors in the form $(v,0)$ and $(v,0)^\prime(X,u)(v,0)=v^\prime X v.$

Comment: @whuber the variance should be $v'(X,u)^T(X,u)v,$ therefore the result is not obvious.

Comment: Replace $X$ by $X^\prime X$ and apply my observation.

Comment: @whuber get your point now. And is there any geometric explanation like I mention in linear regression?

Comment: I had hoped it would be clear that a description phrased in terms of spheres can be considered a geometric one!